# How to access router.navigate() within $.post in Angular 4?

Tags: jquery, angular

Newbie here to Typescript and Angular 4.

The `Continue()` function below fires during a `(click)` event in an html template. As you can see an AJAX post is made with jquery which is all working as expected. However, upon success from the backend, I need to go to a different page and `router.navigate()` is not found.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.page.scss']
})
export class SignupPage implements OnInit {

  @Input() email: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  Continue() {
    $.post( 'https://mydomain/lgn',{email: this.email}, function(data) {
        /* problem here */
        this.router.navigate(['/vemail']);
    });
  }
}
```

**Browser Console Error:**

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.router.navigate')

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to import it into your module like this..

```
import { Router } from @angular/router;
```

and then you need to declare it in your constructor,

```
constructor(public router: Router){}
```

then you will be able to use `this.router.navigate()`

also due to the scope `this` wont work so before your jquery call do this

```
const that = this
```

and then do this instead

```
that.router.navigate();
```

so your call will look like this

```
Continue() {
  const that = this; 
    $.post( 'https://mydomain/lgn',{email: this.email}, function(data) {
        /* problem here */
        that.router.navigate(['/vemail']);
    });
}
```

basically angular runs on arrow functions, so when you use an ES5 function it breaks `this`

or as Simon K points out you could easily do this also and use an arrow function instead of a regular function

```
Continue() {
    $.post( 'https://mydomain/lgn',{email: this.email}, data => {
        /* problem here */
        this.router.navigate(['/vemail']);
    });
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `const that = this` where it can be avoided (99% of cases). You should instead use an arrow function to keep `this` referencing the class. i.e. `$.post( 'https://mydomain/lgn',{email: this.email}, data => { this.router.navigate... });`